# Decrease the font size in Cinnamon from the command line

Tags: linux-mint, fonts, cinnamon, display-settings

While I was playing with Cinnamon settings I set the font size to 990 from the font icon available in cinnamon settings. Now I can't use any applications because of the font. It garbles the whole screen. I cannot redo it because when I somehow manage to open Cinnamon settings, I can't see the font icon, because of the font size, even if I maximize that window. I can see up to icon themes, that's it. Now what to do, Is there any way of setting things to normal? I tried setting Cinnamon settings to default but did not work. Now what to do? Is it possible from a terminal?

Comment: please let me know how to decrease font size somehow from terminal cos I cant do it from cinnamon settings cos of huge font size I cant see that Icon

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and enter:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface font-name 'Sans 10'
```

You may have to go to Cinnamon Settings after this and reset the font as well.

http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=211&t=126875#p692511

Answer (score 1):

An update: 
If using Linux Mint 16 Cinnamon (cinnamon 2.0), the terminal command now is:

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.interface font-name 'Sans 10"
```

If using earlier versions of Cinnamon (eg. LM15, 14 etc.), the original command is correct.

Comment: Why not just edit the original answer?